# multiple values to oracle case statement then

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case, where-clause

Can some one please explain how to pass multiple values to oracle case statement Then

```
SELECT * 
FROM impl_debitor_information 
WHERE soft_delete='F' 
AND SHOP_ID ='4987bc1b-c0a8-6cb7-12f4-0243011f7099' 
AND (debitor_type IS NULL 
     OR debitor_type IN (CASE 
                           WHEN (SELECT techfund_debitor_enabled 
                                 FROM impl_shop 
                                 WHERE shop_id='4987bc1b-c0a8-6cb7-12f4-0243011f7099') = 'YES' THEN ('T','D')                        
                           ELSE 'D'
                         END))
```

If values from 
select techfund_debitor_enabled from impl_shop where shop_id='4987bc1b-c0a8-6cb7-12f4-0243011f7099' is "YES" then I need to pass 2 values to in clause, if not single value
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: CASE can only return a scalar, not an IN LIST.  I would recommend that rewrite this as a UNION to handle the two cases you have.

Comment: Hi @WW thanks for the suggestion, can u please give some more hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE will only return a single value. You must rewrite your query. Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM impl_debitor_information i, impl_shop where shop_id s
WHERE d.soft_delete='F' 
AND d.shop_id ='4987bc1b-c0a8-6cb7-12f4-0243011f7099' 
AND d.shop_id = s.shop_id
AND (d.debitor_type IS NULL 
     OR (d.debitor_type IN ('T','D') AND s.techfund_debitor_enabled = 'YES')
     OR (d.debitor_type IN ('D') AND s.techfund_debitor_enabled <> 'YES'))
```

There might be errors in it, I didn't test the query.